# Image on category page with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm wondering how can I put custom field in category page, is it possible? 
I already used it to display on taxonomy term and its visible on list of all category but no in single category edit page.

[image: description goes here]

Answer (score 0):

ACF data is attached to term ID, so you cannot create it before the term (category) is created. You can only see ACF fields when term is created, so in edit page only. That's how it works.